# Can I access Mask>Mask Path>Shape>BoundingBox properties via Extenscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I am wondering if there's a way to access the Bounding Box Gui properties of mask shapes so that I can see how to create perfect circle shape masks in After Effects?
My code is below:

`maskpath = app.project.item(1).layer("Orange Solid 2").property("ADBE Mask Parade").property("ADBE Mask Atom").property("ADBE Mask Shape");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "access the Bounding Box Gui properties of mask shapes", but I do think I know what you mean by "how to create perfect circle shape masks in After Effects".

See D. Ebberts' script code posted here: http://aenhancers.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2084

I believe it does (or will lead you to do) what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually this also helps. I apologize for the poor description of the 'Bounding Box Gui' . But if you are wondering, it's the gui that opens up when you select your layer mask,mask path & just to the right of that you can select  "Shape..." Which is highlighted in Orange.

Comment: I'm sure it's somewhat obvious, but generally speaking scripting is best used (and APIs are best designed) without relying on GUI, for various reasons. Your description was not poor; I wanted to be sure that's what you meant, since I was thinking of the ideal utilization of a scripting solution, which does not rely on GUI. I'm very glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf page 48

```
AVLayer sourceRectAtTime()  method
```

Retrieves the rectangle bounds of the layer at the specified time index, corrected for text or shape layer content.
Use, for example, to write text that is properly aligned to the baseline.

```
app.project.item(index).layer(index).sourceRectAtTime(timeT, extents)
```

Returns
A JavaScript object with four attributes: [top, left, width, height].

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about how to access Left Top Right Bottom values of this window. 
[image]

This window appears when you click on shape of mask path
(position where pointing hand drown blue color arrow)
[image]

please any one can tell me how to access those values via Script